# Android: Know when ObservableScrollView reach a position

Tags: android, scrollview

I have an observableScrollView with the override method:

```
@Override
    public void onScrollChanged(MyScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
            int oldx, int oldy) {
.
.
.
}
```

It is working great, but what I need is:

I have some positions (900px, 1800px, 2700px...), I need to know when the scrollView.getScrollY() reach these positions. Once a position is reached I want to call a method.
But I want that method is called only once when a position is reached.
So

```
if(scrollView.getScrollY()>900){
myMethod()
}
```

will not work because myMethod() will be called all the time the scroll>900
It is more an algo question. I want to call a method each step the scrollview has reached. Don't know if it is clear...

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean variable set for each position. When the scrollview passes the threshold the boolean is set to true and your method is not triggered again.

If you want it be triggered once again you can rest the boolean once `scrollView.getScrollY() < 900` that way it is called once again when you pass the scrollview going down

```
if (scrollView.getScrollY() > 900 && hasReached900 == false) {
    myMethod();
    hasReached900=true;
} else if (scrollView.getScrollY() < 900) {
    hasReached900=false;
}
```